# "Loneliest point" algorithm

Tags: euclidean-distance, voronoi-diagrams

**Problem:**

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the maximal Euclidean distance between points in a set $R$ and another set $S \subseteq R$.

Specifically, given a finite set of points $S$ in $n$-dimensional space, let $R$ be the minimal bounding box of $S$ (so the product of the bounds across all dimensions). I'm only interested in this type of set $R$, for now, and am ignoring the more general question of finding a solution for any set $R$ containing $S$.

I want to find a distance *D* such that $d(r, S) \le D$ for any $r \in R$, where $d(r, S)$ is the *Euclidean* distance from the point $r$ to its nearest point in $S$. I call the point in $R$ that is maximal distance from $S$ the *loneliest* point in $R$, but I'm not interested in finding this point, just a rough estimate for the distance. In other words, I am looking to estimate:
$$
\max_{r \in R} \min_{s \in S} d(s,r)
$$

**A solution:**

I have an exhaustive solution, as follows: Construct Voronoi diagrams for $S$ in $R$, find the distance from each point $s$ to the furthest vertex in its Voronoi polyhedron, and take the max of all these.

This reduces the continuous space $R$ to a discrete and finite set of candidate points whose nearest point in $S$ I know, and over which it's easy to take the max.

**Why this is inadequate:**

This works fine for low-dimensional data, but it does not scale well to bigger data sets. I'm sure there must be a better, approximate solution. I don't need exact values, I just need an estimate to some predefined degree of accuracy.

**Use case:**

The use case here is that I am trying to fix an upper bound for the Euclidean distance that a point can be from a given data set in a design space, so that I can have a constistent scale across the space.

**Problem:**

Is anyone aware of such an algorithm? It seems like it should be an established problem but I haven't so far found an easy solution. Feels like it should be related to nearest-neighbour somehow.

Comment: Why does your solution find the distance to the farthest and not the closest vertex in the Voronoi cell of each vertex? Aren't you maximizing the smallest distance?

Comment: Because the farthest vertex of the Voronoi cell will be further from S than the nearest vertex, and will thus be a "lonelier" point in R.

Comment: Just to clarify: is R axis-aligned? The "product of bounds across all dimensions" suggest it is, but the Voronoi diagram of S does not depend on the choice of axis. Do I understand correctly that you clip the Voronoi diagram of S by the bounding box R?

Comment: Hi @MSalters! In general, no, $R$ could be any set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contains $S$ as a subset.

In my particular use case, however, I am using $R = \Pi_{i \leq n} (\text{range of } S \text{ in dimension i}) $. I'll update the answer, because I don't really need the more general solution.

Comment: And yes, I clip the Voronoi diagram.